How to execute deep link in Flutter app with url?
[What I want]

User sends certain url to friend -> https://hayatshin.github.io/userId
Once friend clicks url then app is opened and userId is passed to app

[What I did]
I deploy https://hayatshin.github.io based on documentation

path: .well-known/apple-app-site-association

{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "TeamID.AppBundleID"
        ],
        "paths": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


path: .well-known/applinks.json

[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.chugnchunon.packagename",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["3B:38:~~~"]
    }
  }
]


I checked that app is opened with each terminal code of android and ios debug mode.

[Android]
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
  -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
  -d "https://hayatshin.github.io"' \
  com.chugnchunon.packagename

[iOS]
xcrun simctl openurl booted https://hayatshin.github.io

BUT
When I share https://hayatshin.github.io link url to friend, and friend clicks that url, it doesn't open app. It just shows index.html of that domain.
And especially I share https://hayatshin.github.io/userId, it throws 404 error.
I also tested as uploading app on market, result is same.
As far as I know, dynamic link makes app executed with url link, but what if url is not opened unless it is executed with terminal?
How to make it work? or Is there any workaround?
Please help me.

what navigation package are you using, go_router(https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) is the best for handling such scenario.
